# .NET Core Identity UI - overriding SignInManager<IdentityUser>

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I try:

```
public class VoySignInManager : SignInManager<IdentityUser>
{
    public VoySignInManager(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser> userManager, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser> claimsFactory, Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser>> logger, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
        : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes)
    {
    }

    public override Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(IdentityUser user, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
    {
        return Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult.Success;
    }
}
```

I get:

```
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult>'
```

What am I doing wrong ? how do I return a successful SignInResult here ?

(note obviously this is just a simplified version to show the error)

Answer (score 1):

No async/await needed.  Just return your result as `return Task.FromResult(SignInResult.Success);`

Answer (score 0):

You lack `async` when define function:

```
public override async Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(IdentityUser user, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
{
    return await Task.FromResult(SignInResult.Success);
}
```

Comment: but I generated this function using visual studio generate overrides ? it's not async in the base ...

Comment: if I add async I get: warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

Comment: I am not sure about why generator didn't add async into override function

Comment: @kofifus I updated my answer with return, please try it.

Comment: ok this builds but I am trying to understand why I need await in my override when the base class doesn't have it ?

Comment: I don't think this is correct, if I try instead for example return base.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, isPersistent, lockoutOnFailure); it does not build

Comment: This doesn't require `async / await`.  Should work with just `return Task.FromResult(SignInResult.Success);`